# Trouble getting my navigation to go over a head that fades in on rollover

Tags: html, css, z-index, rollover

I am working on a website and I need a header that is basically a transparent box, and fades in when you roll over it (see horizonsupply.co). I so far have successfully created the header, along with a logo, and it works perfectly, but when I try to put in the navigation, it either sits underneath the fade-in box, not allowing links to be clicked (i am using z-index's as well) or if I set the z-index of the navigation to a number above what the fade-in box is at, it doesnt allow for the box to fade in on roll over. Hopefully that makes sense. Basically I'm trying to recreate what horizonsupply.co has going on.

Here is the html I have:

```
<div id="logo" >
    <img src="images/weblogo.png" alt="weblogo">
</div>

<div id="navigation" class="clearfix">
    <div id="navlinks"> 
        <ul>
            <a href="#"><li>ABOUT</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>EPISODES</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>CONTACT</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="header"></div>

<div id="main" class="clearfix">
    <img src="images/1415210745666.jpeg" alt="1415210745666" width="100%" height="675">

    <div id="content">
        <div id="episodebox"></div>
        <div id="episodebox2"></div>
        <div id="episodebox3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my CSS:

```
#header{
    width:100%;
    height:205px;
    background-color:#2D2D2D;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;

     opacity: 0; /* Change this to .5 for 50% opacity */
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
       -moz-transition: .5s;
        -ms-transition: .5s;
         -o-transition: .5s;
            transition: .5s;    
}

#header:hover {
     opacity: 0.87;
}

#body{
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

.img{
     max-width:100%; 
     max-height:100%;
}

#logo{
     position:absolute;
     width:auto;
     height:auto;
     padding-left:25px;
     padding-top:10px;
     z-index:3;
}

#navigation.clearfix{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding-top:160px;
    padding-left:15px;
    z-index:1;
    clear:both;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top:auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
}

li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding:1%;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #F46969;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight:500;
}

#main.clearfix{
    clear:both;
}

#content{
    width:960px;
    height:900px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin-top:150px;
}

#episodebox{
    width:270px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#ffa9a9;
    margin-left:37px;
    margin-right:18px;
    float:left;
}

#episodebox2{
    width:270px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#ffa9a9;
    margin-left:18px;
    margin-right:18px;
    float:left;
}

#episodebox3{
    width:270px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#ffa9a9;
    margin-left:18px;
    margin-right:37px;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to this, one of the simplest solutions is to wrap the entire contents (logo, links, etc) with your header div then manipulate the `background-color` instead of `opacity`.

```css
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 205px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
  -ms-transition: .5s;
  -o-transition: .5s;
  transition: .5s;
}
#header:hover {
  background-color: rgba(45, 45, 45, .85);
}
#body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
#logo {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  z-index: 3;
}
#navigation.clearfix {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 160px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  z-index: 1;
  clear: both;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1%;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #F46969;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}
#main.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
#content {
  width: 960px;
  height: 900px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
#episodebox {
  width: 270px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ffa9a9;
  margin-left: 37px;
  margin-right: 18px;
  float: left;
}
#episodebox2 {
  width: 270px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ffa9a9;
  margin-left: 18px;
  margin-right: 18px;
  float: left;
}
#episodebox3 {
  width: 270px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ffa9a9;
  margin-left: 18px;
  margin-right: 37px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/50" alt="weblogo">
  </div>

  <div id="navigation" class="clearfix">
    <div id="navlinks">
      <ul>
        <a href="#">
          <li>ABOUT</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>EPISODES</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li>CONTACT</li>
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="main" class="clearfix">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/700/700" alt="1415210745666" width="100%" height="675">

  <div id="content">
    <div id="episodebox"></div>
    <div id="episodebox2"></div>
    <div id="episodebox3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Marcelo gave the best solution, I would just suggest to move a tags inside of li

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</li></a>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</li></a>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</li></a>
</ul>
```